# How to sort an array by specific filter?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Lets say, I have an array like this:

```
$arr = array('M', '38', '37', '3XL', 'XL', '39', 'L', 'S', '36', '41', '40', 'XXL');
```

(its array with available sizes of shoes for current item that customer is going to order)

How to sort it ascending (first alpha-sizes: S, M, L, XL, XXL, 3XL; and then numeric-sizes: 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41), so I will get array:

```
$res = array('S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', '3XL', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41');
```

Is there some function to do that?

Comment: I think you will have to write your own function.

Comment: Or you need to differentiate on your own where alpha values will be key and numeric values will be values to their respective keys as `array([s] => 36)`

Comment: @Uchiha: Yes, that could work, I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sizes are all defined, then you can have a `$baseArr` containing all valid sizes and sort the current arr based on that

```
function sortSizeArr($arr) {
    $baseArr = array('S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', '3XL', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41');
    $sortedArr = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($baseArr); $i++) {
        if(in_array($baseArr[$i], $arr))
            array_push($sortedArr, $baseArr[$i]);
    }
    return $sortedArr;
}
```

Test:

```
$sizes = array('M', '38', 'S', '36', '41', '40', 'XXL');
print_r(sortSizeArr($sizes));
```

> Array ( [0] => S [1] => M [2] => XXL [3] => 36 [4] => 38 [5] => 40 [6]
>   => 41 )

**EDITED by Legionar:**
I am calling this function, only if there are alpha-sizes, without numerical-sizes. Some sizes are f.e. `M/5, L/6, XL/7, XXL/8`, so I changed little bit your function. This helped me, thanks:

```
function sortSizeArr($arr) {
    $baseArr = array('XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL', '3XL');

    $sortedArr = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($baseArr); $i++) {
        /*if (in_array($baseArr[$i], $arr)) {
            array_push($sortedArr, $baseArr[$i]);
        }*/

        foreach ($arr as $val) {
            $check = reset(explode('/', $val));

            if (strpos($val, $baseArr[$i]) === 0) {
                array_push($sortedArr, $val);
            }
        }
    }

    return $sortedArr;
}
```

Comment: Theoretically they could be defined, but they arent, especially numeric-sizes.

Comment: So, is it that you always have a second array to sort the first one based on that? Or the letters are always the same and come first and then come the numbers in an ascending order?

Comment: I will try to use your solution, but will sort only alpha-sizes, they could be defined without problems :-)

Comment: If you always have a second array you can pass it to the function and then instead of the current `$baseArr` use the passed array.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the function `usort()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

It allows you to sort an array using a custom compare function. Implementing this function should be rather straightforward for your case.

Comment: This vague hint to read the manual could have been a comment under the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example for sort array alphabetically then numerically:

```
<?php

$array = array('M', '38', '37', '3XL', 'XL', '39', 'L', 'S', '36', '41', '40', 'XXL');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (ctype_digit($value)) {
        $array[$key] = intval($value);
    }
}

sort($array);

echo "After Sorting".'<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

For your reference and output [Click Here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q94Na0)

Comment: But this will not sort alpha-sizes as `'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', '3XL'`, no?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the numeric sizes to be anything you can do something like:

```
function size_sort($a, $b) {
    return determine_value($a) < determine_value($b) ? -1 : 1;
}

function determine_value($var) {
    $letter_sizes = array("S" => 1, "M" => 2, "L" => 3, "XL" => 4, "XXL" => 5, "3XL" => 6);
    if(array_key_exists($var, $letter_sizes))
        return $letter_sizes[$var];
    elseif(is_numeric($var))
        return $var + 100; // add 100 so its value is higher than any letter sizing
    else
        return 10000; // unknown size, make sure it is at the end
}
usort($arr, "size_sort");
```

I added an else condition incase any letter sizes are left out (ie, XS, 4XL, etc)

Answer (score 1):

To add variant. with only suggestion that sizes nore than 7:

```
$arr = array('M', '38', '37', '3XL', 'XL', '39', 'L', 'S', '36', '41', '40', 'XXL');

$sizes = array('S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', '3XL');
var_export($arr);
usort($arr, function ($a, $b){ 
        global $sizes;
        $a = is_numeric($a) ? $a : array_search($a, $sizes);
        $b = is_numeric($b) ? $b : array_search($b, $sizes);
        return $a-$b;
});
var_export($arr);
```

Comment: Beware of cases where `array_search()` can return `0` or `false` which will be compared equally.